# How do I finish this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select * from workers where id = uid and age = uage`   -- sql1
select uid,uage from users where uage>20`              -- sql2
```

I want to use `sql2` as the condition of `sql1`, i.e. the `uid` and `uage` used in `sql1` is come from `sql2`.

Comment: We can certainly help you with the syntax but I'm not sure what you really want to return here - if you're querying on the ID why would you need an age?

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join both tables:

```
SELECT w.*
FROM workers w
INNER JOIN users u
ON w.id = u.uid AND w.age = u.uage
WHERE u.uage > 20
```

Comment: He or Her want to use sql2 as the condition of sql1 not `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @MarkYao - And with this `JOIN` the op is getting that result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do nested queries with a temporary table. Thr first query creates a temp table which the second one queries.

Answer (score -1):

You can use subquery.
code:

```
select * from workers where (id,age) =(select uid,uage from users where uage>20);
```

Comment: @Wiseguy Before you vote down, you need to learn more about mysql subsquery.

Comment: My question was rhetorical. I wasn't actually asking; I meant to state that it would not work if the subquery returns more than one row. However, it should work if you change `=` to `IN`.